# Why does Nullable!(Nullable!int) refuse to compile?

Tags: d, phobos

The following code refuses to compile:

```
Nullable!(Nullable!int) nni = Nullable!(Nullable!int)(10);
```

With this error message:

```
Error: inout method nullable.Nullable!(Nullable!(immutable(int))).Nullable.this is not callable using a mutable object
```

Why?

Comment: Why do you want to have a nullable of a nullable? You want to achieve this? "It can either be null or have a value that can be null or have a value" Beyond me why you want to do it. If you could explain to me a good situation for it, perhaps I could see a situation where I might need it in the future, but I've never come across it, so pardon me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a bad error message.

The argument to the constructor of `Nullable!(T)` is `T`. In this case, `T` is a `Nullable!int`, but you're passing in an `int`. You need to wrap the `int` in a nullable.

```
Nullable!(Nullable!int) foo = Nullable!(Nullable!int)(Nullable!int(10));
```

Comment: Gosh, that looks terrible, does it not? :) Five times `Nullable` in a single line...

Comment: @DejanLekic You can use `auto` in the variable declaration to reduce it to three. Not that there's a point to doubling up on `Nullable` anyway.

Comment: alias Nullable!int InnerNullable; and using it with auto foo = Nullable!InnerNullable(InnerNullable(10)); improves it somewhat